# Issue using FILE* with std::getline()

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to get some advice on an issue I've encountered once working on small adjustments to an existing program.

The program itself has to:

1. Open a file and read it line-by-line preferably
2. Pack the lines into `istringstream` and then split to 2 strings on a `':'` separator
3. Insert those 2 strings `line1` and `line2` into an existing `std::map` container
4. Than I can do more stuff with the `map` and the data from it.

My code looks like that:

```cpp
int main()
{
    FILE *fpFile;
    map<string, string>mapOfPci;
    std::string tempBuff="";
    std::string line1="", line2="";
        
    fpFile = fopen(PCI_MAPPING_PATH, "r");
    
    if(!fpFile)
        return false;
    
    while(getline(fpFile, tempBuff)){
        istringstream iSs(tempBuff);
        iSs >> line1;
        iSs.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ':');
        iSs >> line2;
        mapOfPci.insert(make_pair(line1, line2)); 
    }
    for(const auto &m : mapOfPci){
        cout << m.first << " : " << m.second << "\n";
    }
    
    fclose(fpFile);
    return (0);
}
```

Now what I'm getting in my compiler feedback is:

```
mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>' and 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}'
  while(getline(fpFile, tempBuff))
```

At this point I presume that this is due to the usage of `FILE*` file handling method.

I might not be able to use the C++ `std::ifstream`, `std::fstream`, so is there any method to move this further with the current `FILE*` usage?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use std::ifstream? You're using C++(11) not C.

Comment: *I might not be able to use the C++ std::ifstream, std::fstream* -- So did you try using `std::ifstream`?  If you did, did your code work?  If it does work, then what is the concern?  Maybe you should have stated why a working solution using `ifstream` is not an option.

Comment: @P Kramer: changing this to std::ifstream, std::fstream would require a large amount of changes in files that are associated deeper with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::getline()` expects an `std::istream`-derived class, like `std::ifstream`, so you simply can't pass your own `FILE*` to it (unless you wrap it inside of a custom `std::streambuf`-derived object assigned to a standard `std::istream` object. `std::ifstream` uses `std::filebuf`, which uses `FILE*` internally, but you can't supply it with your own `FILE*`).

Otherwise, you can use C's [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function instead, but it doesn't work with `std::string`, as it allocates its own output `char[]` buffer which you will then have to free afterwards (you can assign the contents of that buffer to a `std::string`, though), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *fpFile = fopen(PCI_MAPPING_PATH, "r");
    if (!fpFile)
        return false;
    
    map<string, string> mapOfPci;
    char *tempBuff = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
    int nRead;

    while ((nRead = getline(&tempBuff, &size, fpFile)) != -1){
        istringstream iSs(string(tempBuff, nRead));
        string line1, line2;
        iSs >> line1;
        iSs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ':');
        iSs >> line2;
        mapOfPci.insert(make_pair(line1, line2)); 
        free(tempBuff); tempBuff = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    free(tempBuff);

    for(const auto &m : mapOfPci){
        cout << m.first << " : " << m.second << "\n";
    }
    
    fclose(fpFile);
    return 0;
}
```

But, since you are using other C++ standard classes, there really is no good reason not to use `std::ifstream` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fpFile(PCI_MAPPING_PATH);
    if (!fpFile.is_open())
        return false;
    
    map<string, string> mapOfPci;
    string tempBuff;

    while (getline(fpFile, tempBuff)){
        istringstream iSs(tempBuff);
        string line1, line2;
        iSs >> line1;
        iSs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ':');
        iSs >> line2;
        mapOfPci.insert(make_pair(line1, line2)); 
    }

    for(const auto &m : mapOfPci){
        cout << m.first << " : " << m.second << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help. As I answered above - cannot shift to ifstream/fstream as it would require a lot of modifications for the other files. Originally the data type was char[SOME_DEFINED_SIZE]; |I wanted to shift it to std::string.